# SQL Server 2016 Basic Availablity Group Limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, high-availability, failover

I was wondering if any one could tell me if BAG can still span multiple physical locations as long as they are part of the same Window Server Failover Cluster ?

Comment: if they are part of same domain ,then yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, availability groups can span multiple locations. In this scenario, you may wish to put a fileshare quorum in a 3rd data center.

I would recommend only using asynchronous commit between data centers. If you need synchronous commit (automatic failover) then ensure that the network latency between data centers is < 6ms